# Dynamically show a range of years from 2000 to 2005

Tags: jquery

Simple question:

Dynamically show range of years from 2000 to 2005.

Just text is perfect.

example

2000
2001
2002
2003
2004
2005

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$("#years").dynamicallyshow2000to2005();`? On a more serious note, please explain what you mean by "dynamic".

Comment: And are you looking for the output to be literal text, or options in a select list, or radio buttons, or list items, or...?

Comment: What is dynamic about it if the range is static?

Comment: your absolutely correct. Its not dynamic my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i = 2000; i <= 2005; i++) {
   $('#selectelement').append($('<option>' + i + '</option>'));
}
```

boy, rocket science sure does get more complicated every day...